# Docker - Ruby Dependencies installed at build time not available at container up

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile

I am running the following command in my `Dockerfile`:

```
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gnupg2

    RUN gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
    RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
    RUN /bin/bash -l -c ". /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm install 2.3.1 && rvm use --default 2.3.1 && gem install bundler"
    # some more code
    ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

In my `entrypoint.sh`, I am running `bundle install`.  But it's throwing error:

> bundle not found

Upon further investigation, I found that none of the dependencies installed during Docker build time seem to be available at container run time.  I am probably missing something very basic.  Help very appreciated.

Comment: Does your entrypoint load rvm?

Comment: Do you mean `source rvm`?  It does not..

Comment: My suggestion anyway is to use something like `FROM ruby:2.5-alpine3.7` instead of installing a ruby through rvm during docker build.

Comment: That's the reason then, the entrypoint won't see any rubies or bundlers if it's not using the rvm installed ruby.

Comment: I did try that.  And it worked like butter.  But there are security vulnerabilities in official ruby images and hence can't be used.  

I cannot use ruby 2.5, have to stick to ruby 2.3.

Comment: @user3309314 What would a better way be?  I have tried using official ruby images, but they have security vulnerabilities..

Comment: You can use plain alpine and `apk add ruby` or ubuntu/debian and `apt-get install ruby`

Comment: Intrigued what are these vulnerabilities you're talking about, I've been using them in production for ages, I hope they're not bad.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/248

Comment: Does it helps if you update appropriate packages and build that way new image?

Comment: @user3309314 Pardon my ignorance here, but I am unsure how one can update specific packages in docker.

Comment: Offtopic, like most of this, if you need to use ruby 2.3 (probably not, version migrations have been easy or required no changes for a couple of ruby versions), at least use 2.3.8 instead of 2.3.1, there are some vulnerabilities in ruby itself fixed, such as https://blog.heroku.com/identifying-ruby-ftp-cve

Answer (score 1):

The `entrypoint.sh` does not load `rvm`, so it doesn't see the `rvm`-installed Ruby or its `bundler`.

Load `rvm` in the `entrypoint.sh` by adding `. /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` and `rvm use ..` before Ruby is used.